# Sql Select Distint Count

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I had an interesting situation where I wanted to count DISTINCT rows with variable values.

Imagine a table like this:

```
**Customer  City        status**
Acme        Sydney      Exist
Bally       Sydney      new exist
Bally       Melbourne   new exist
Costco      Melbourne   Exist
David       Sydney      null
Ego         Japan       Exist
Dave        Sydney      Exist
```

I’m looking for this result:
group by Status "Exist"

```
**City      status**
Sydney      2
Japan       1
Melbourne   1
```

How to create sql query for this result

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql ?

Comment: using mysql, your code result single row not work

Comment: @ladyWomen srry should group by city

Comment: it kind of bad explain

Comment: @ladyWomen when was working ?

Comment: hi thank dude, it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT [City], COUNT(status)
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
WHERE [status] LIKE '%exist%'
GROUP BY [City]
```

This may work.

Comment: if you are using mysql should remove [] and use ``

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
select city, count(*)
from t
where status = 'Exist'
group by city;
```